# how to grab database values to edit form in dropdown input in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5

I am developing web application using laravel. In my application I have data entry form and in this form I have one optional value selections input

```
<label for="status" class="control-label">Choose Status</label>
<select name="status" id="status">
  <option value="">Choose a status</option>
  <option value="Upcoming">Upcoming</option>
  <option value="Active">Active</option>
  <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
</select>
@if ($errors->has('status'))
  <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</span>
@endif
```

Now I need develop edit data form some of my data in the data table. In this form I need show selection input field in edit page with current values in the data table. and select optional values if user go to the edit. then how can I develop selection field in the edit blade file.

**Edited**

```
<select name="assign" id="status">
                    <option value="{!! $task->assign !!}">{!! $task->assign !!}</option>
                    {{ getstatus($task->assign) }}
                </select>
                @if ($errors->has('assign'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('assign') }}</span>
                @endif
```

what about this edited optional input fields. it is working but not displaying other optional values.

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: No any idea here

Comment: please see My edited answer